# Creating a Welcome page interface with GUI in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hey I’m having some trouble creating a GUI welcome page interface and was hoping somebody could help with it.

The GUI has to look like:
[image]

Box 1 has to be the frame for the whole interface without outline.
Box 2 should be a text box.
Box 3 should be a input textbox (Alphanumeric string for names).
Box 4 should be a input textbox (Alphanumeric string for the password).
Box 5 should be a button with textbox to continue to the next page (only if password in box 4 is correct).

So far what I have managed to program is:

```
####### Welcome Page Interface med lille skærm #######

import tkinter
#import TkFileDialog
#import tkMessageBox

from tkinter import *

def main ():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Welcome Page Interface")
    root.minsize(width = 1370, height = 700)
    root.maxsize(width = 1370, height = 700)

    button2 = Button(root, text = "Textbox", width = 150, height = 10)
    button2.pack(side = TOP, padx = 1, pady = 50 )
    button2.pack()

    button3 = Button(root, text = "Input textbox", width = 20, height = 2)
    button3.pack(side = TOP, padx = 10, pady = 100 )
    button3.pack()

    button4 = Button(root, text = "Input textbox #Password#", width = 30, height = 500)
    button4.pack(side = BOTTOM, padx = 10, pady = 140 )
    button4.pack()

    button5 = Button(root, text = "Continue to the next page", width = 30, height = 1)
    button5.pack(side = BOTTOM, padx = 10, pady= 110 )
    button5.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


###############################


#from tkinter import *

#root = Tk()

#Label(root, text="First Name").grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx=4)
#Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

#Label(root, text="Last Name").grid(row=1, sticky=W, padx=4)
#Entry(root).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

#Button(root, text="Submit").grid(row=3)

#root.mainloop()

###############################
#import tkinter
#import TkFileDialog
#import tkMessageBox

#from tkinter import *

#def main ():
#    root = Tk()
#    root.title("Welcome Page Interface")
#    root.minsize(width = 1370, height = 700)
#    root.maxsize(width = 1370, height = 700)

#    button2 = Button(root, text="Textbox", width=150, height=10)
#        button2.pack(side = TOP, padx = 1, pady = 50 )
#        button2.pack()



#    Label(root, text="").grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx=4)

#    Label(root, text="B").grid(row=4, sticky=E, padx=8)
#    Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=E, pady=5)

#    Label(root, text="H").grid(row=4, sticky=W, padx=5)
#    Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E, pady=5)

##########


#    Label(root, text="First Name").grid(row=0, sticky=W, padx=4)
#    Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E, pady=4)

#    Label(root, text="Last Name").grid(row=7, sticky=W, padx=5)
#    Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E, pady=4)

#    Button(root, text="Submit").grid(row=3)

#    root.mainloop()


#if __name__ == "__main__":
#    main()
```

But my buttons keep being in the way for each other and I can’t get it to work.

Hope somebody can help.

I'm using Python 3.6.2 if it is possible in Python 2.7.12 that would be fine to.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- The `height` argument for buttons is in lines of text, not pixels. 500 is completely unreasonable.
- The `pady` argument is in pixels top AND bottom. So `pady=140` puts the widget in the center of a 280 pixel tall field.
- Pick a side and stick to it for all the widgets. `TOP` is default.
- You only need to call `pack` once per widget.
- Use the `Entry` widget for getting text from the user.
- Don't use wildcard imports.

-

```
import tkinter as tk

def main ():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Welcome Page Interface")
    root.minsize(width = 1370, height = 700)
    root.maxsize(width = 1370, height = 700)

    button2 = tk.Label(root, text = "Textbox", width = 150, height = 10, relief=tk.RAISED)
    button2.pack(padx = 1, pady = 50 )

    username_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    label = tk.Label(username_frame, text="Username")
    label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    button3 = tk.Entry(username_frame, width = 20)
    button3.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    username_frame.pack(padx = 10, pady = 50 )

    button4 = tk.Entry(root, width = 30)
    button4.pack(padx = 10, pady = 20 )

    button5 = tk.Button(root, text = "Continue to the next page", width = 30, height = 1)
    button5.pack(padx = 10, pady= 20 )

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Hey Novel, but how would you input the "username" on the left side of "button3" and Password on the left side of "button4" when you do it this way?

Comment: You mean the Label? You will need to make a subframe. I edited my response to show you.

Comment: Hey Novel, sorry for the late answer, I have a problem now where I can't get the password next to the other Label.

password_frame = tk.Frame(root)

    label = tk.Label(password_frame, text="Password")

    label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    button4 = tk.Entry(root, width = 30)

    button4.pack(padx = 10, pady = 20 )

    password_frame.pack(padx=1, pady=5)


What am I doing rung?

Comment: @Tvvt you need to use 'password_frame', not 'root', as the master. You may be want to post questions like this in reddit.com/r/learnpython in the future; they are a more beginner friendly environment.

Comment: Hey Novel, thanks a lot. I have tried reading some from "Python and Tkinter programming" by John E. Grayson and watched some youtube videos and at last I have read "Python for Informatics Exploring Information" by Charles Severance. Do you have any books that you can recommend regarding working with Tkinter in Python?

Thanks in advance.